# most frequent words in list which contains lists

Tags: python, nlp

I have a dataset of a list which contains other lists and I want to find the top 1000 words

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

from collections import Counter
counts_top1000 = [word for word, word_count in Counter(mainlist).most_common(1000)]

Note that my dataset is 'mainlist'.

I would be grateful if you have any more ideas.

Comment: Do the inner lists contain the words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the data looks something like `mainlist = [[word11, word12, ...], [word21, word22, ...], ...]`, you can do the following

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
Counter(chain(*mainlist)).most_common(100)
```